# Protected Question Requires 10 Rep, Cannot Post with 101

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just joined this site and being an active member on stack overflow gave me 100 reputation points.

I went to answer [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30248/obama-said-states-with-the-most-gun-laws-tend-to-have-the-fewest-gun-deaths-w) and found the banner:

[image]

There is no button to post an answer.

I think this might be a bug.

Comment: Fun fact: as an employee who has a diamond on every site, I can't answer a protected question unless I earn 10 rep the old-fashioned way on the site itself.

Comment: @JonEricson Stack Exchange has some of the most well thought out forum rules ever.  I wonder why as an employee and mod you can't do that?

Comment: Well, one reason is that every site has a unique community behind it. Skeptics, in particular, has rules and customs quite different from the rest of the network. Experience on, say, Cooking won't help me learn how to answer certain questions on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug: it requires 10 reputation gained *on this site*. Your reputation gained on this site is 0, you have 1 starting rep, and 100 association bonus which doesn't count for this.

Comment: I see.  Never knew there was a distinction made.  I mean the rep works for other privileges right?

Comment: Yep, it's only protection that restricts answering to 11 for new users and 111 for network trusted users

Comment: May I suggest the banners be aware of the association bonus and show 110 instead of 10 when appropriate.

Comment: @BAR 111 i believe.